# ListView setActivated(). Same item in multiple lists

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a Two pane layout:

- **Pane A**: This is a ViewPager with 5 ListFragments.
- **Pane B**: When you click on an item in Pane A in any of the lists, setActivated(true) is executed on the list item view, and Pane B content updates.

**Few additional points:**

- An item in one list could appear in any of the other lists.
- Each item in every list comes is the same type of data in the database.
- setActivated() is currently executed in onListItemClick() method of my ListFragment.

**My question:**

When clicking on an item, setActivated(true) is used on that item to highlight the row as being the currently activated one shown in the content. But when the user uses the ViewPager to scroll to another list, the item might exist in another list as well, and I want to highlight that as activated as well.

So what do you think is the best way to achieve this inter-fragment communication reasonably elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is how I solved this and I'm pretty happy with it..

- When the user clicks on an item in a list is does two things. 1) Changes the content. 2) Sends out a broadcast intent stating that the item of a specific ID is now being displayed.
- Each ListFragment then implements a BroadcastReceiver for the above intent. This BroadcastReceiver is registered and unregistered in the onPause/onResume fragment methods.
- The BroadcastRecievers run a method which checks the current visible items displayed in the ListView. The logic for this method goes something like this...

.

```
private void setVisibleItemActivated(Long id)
{
    for (int i = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition(); i <= getListView().getLastVisiblePosition(); i++)
    {
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor) getListView().getItemAtPosition(i);
        Long gameId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        View view = getListView().getChildAt(i);

        if (view.isActivated())
        {
            if (gameId != id)
                view.setActivated(false);
        }
        else
        {
            if (gameId == id)
                view.setActivated(true);
        }
    }
}
```

...So it checks to see if the ID is currently visible in that list.

- But if the item is not visible and still in the list, the list adapter bindView() method which initialises the view of the item when it becomes visible sets the activation state of the view.

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner way to do this, if all these fragments belong to the same activity, is probably to have an ui-less fragment that holds the list you want to share.
Just be cautious, you don't want any view in that list, just data, unless you are keen to create memory leaks.
As a bonus, you can use `setRetainInstance(true)` on that ui less fragment to persist your items during rotations.

Comment: But I don't want to share a list between multiple fragments. I'm not sure how this answers the question.

Comment: Yes you want to. How else are you going to share your items states among multiple fragments ?

Comment: The data is in the database fetched with a CursorAdapter, so why would you hold another copy of the list in another fragment in memory? I'm looking for a decent pattern to solve this problem and not a very loose description of how to share data between multiple Fragments. setRetainInstance() is a method to retain instances of Fragments across activity re-creation and has nothing to do with the question at all.